# String as equation in R

Tags: r

I have a list of tables as follows

```
testinjest <- list("BN 01_181102_103545.data"=
  data.frame(V1 = c(1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L),
   V2 = c(28.359069, 28.357302, 28.359111, 28.353656), 
   V3 = c(0.008764, 0.009662, 0.010677, 0.011763), 
   V4 = c(9e-06, 1.2e-05, 8e-06, 3e-06), 
   V5 = c(6e-06, 9e-06, 1e-05, 4e-06), 
   V6 = c(-152.4882, -151.2109, -150.5143, -150.6976)),
"BN 03_181102_105741.data"=
  data.frame(V1 = c(1000L, 1100L, 1200L, 1300L), 
   V2 = c(28.359069, 28.357302, 28.359111, 28.353656), 
   V3 = c(0.008764, 0.009662, 0.010677, 0.011763), 
   V4 = c(9e-06, 1.2e-05, 8e-06, 3e-06), 
   V5 = c(8e-06,3e-06, 1e-05, 8e-06), 
   V6 = c(-152.862, -151.5966, -150.7392, -151.165)))
```

Using the following function obtains the desired result

```
  lapply(testinjest,transform,V6=V6+200)
```

But I want to be able to pass the equation in with a string. Which does not appear to do anything.

```
lapply(testinjest,transform,eval(parse(text="V6=V6+200")))
```

Does anyone know of a way for the transform/lapply to accept strings as the equation?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, @Daniel the equation is for R chunk or latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `within` would make this easier than transform. The latter requires you use have named parameters to the function which are messy. If you just do assignments to the data environment, it's a bit easier to fake.

```
lapply(testinjest, within, eval(parse(text="V6=V6+200")))
```

But in general working with code as a string is not straightforward thing to do.

Comment: Thank you! that was way simpler than everything else I tried.